# Does anyone knows how to configure Netbeans C++ compiler for OpenMP?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, netbeans

I am trying to run a simple parallel c++ code on Netbeans. just including omp.h does not work. any experiences? should I configure Netbeans somehow?
I am using Cygwin compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `-fopenmp` option to the compiler driver (i.e. g++). It will take care of enabling openmp support during compilation, and also pass for you the necessary linker options.